# Upvotes while I had low rep not updated

Tags: support, upvotes

Hard to phrase the title of the question but essentially:

With low rep, I couldn't up-vote, but there is a message saying that once I gain enough reputation that my up-votes would go through.

I spent a lot of time on SO before ever posting anything so I had voted lots. I recently got enough rep to vote and now all those votes I did previously don't seem to be on my profile.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Your previous votes when you do not have enough reputation are simply not recorded. Just go back and upvote them now.

Comment: With the error message presented, it made it seem like SO was keeping track of what I was upvoting and the votes would go through when I got enough rep

Comment: That's not how it works. Those votes weren't registered.

Comment: The message you get is: `"Thanks for your feedback. Once you earn a total of 15 reputation your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."` It's ever so slightly ambiguous, but the meaning is that once you have 15 rep, votes you cast from *that point onwards* will count.

Comment: @Cerbrus not accurate. The votes are registered, we can even see them in SEDE, but just not in the "main" votes table.

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: The text you get is not 100% clear, so maybe that should be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your votes will only be recorded on your profile once you reach the [Vote Up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) privilege at a reputation of 15.

Until that moment your votes are recorded as [postfeedback](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406026)<sup>1</sup> what started as a feature explained in [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing) and this was further elaborated on in [What should we do with anonymous user feedback?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99370/what-should-we-do-with-anonymous-user-feedback).

So your votes are not lost but there isn't a recovery operation once you reach 15 reputation to re-write history.

<sup>1. Thanks to ShadowWizard to provide the [query](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4301968#4301968)</sup>

Comment: `Once you earn a total of 15 reputation your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.`

That's a rather ambiguous message IMO. It doesn't make clear that `your votes` does not include the ones you cast before having the privilege to cast votes.